# How to avoid text with a lot of line breaks?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating a forum for learning purposes and I have found a problem. Users can post a message (max 255 characters) but they also can send 255 characters with new lines so my forum appearance looks ugly, example:

[image: ugly display line break]

How can I solve this? Any solution?

Comment: try this if u have text area, this is in pure javascript  `constrainInput = (event) => { 
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[\r\n\v]+/g, '')
}

document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('keyup', constrainInput)
})`

Comment: I am not sure I have ever seen a post like this on any well established forum I visited that allows as many line breaks as the user wants to add. I don't think that should be a problem and as @MagnusEriksson said, removing all the line breaks is not a solution to this. Maybe you can say smth like: max 255 chars and max 3 paragraphs

Comment: Does it matter? If someone keeps doing that, can't you just remove the post and kick them out for spamming/trolling?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson right :)

Comment: @magnusErikssonYeah this is probably not a solution but 255 characters approxes to 51 words if you consider each word is of 5 characters, and thats not very long !

Comment: maybe you guys are right and I should let people do that, but I was thinking on limit the paragraphs because it's more like a 4chan forum, when people write short comments usually

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all line breaks with php:
`$newdata = str_replace("\n" ," ", $data);`
$data is the string that users input.

Comment: I believe the OP asks for a solution to do it on the client side rather than server side. for not allowing the users to do that in the first place

Comment: and the `"\n"` should be replaced by `" "` otherwise the words on new lines will be unified which is not a good solution